# Using query analyzer in Solr for exact search on words with special charectors

Tags: search, solr, special-characters

I am trying to search in Solr for exact match. Problem is this kind of data:
test score
test-score
test_score
test+score
If i use exact search with query test score it will result only one record.
I need to find all four.
One way is to copy this field and replace these special characters which is creating a new index requirement so that original content is saved separately.

```
<fieldType name="text_exact_dehyphen" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\s*-\s*" replacement=" "/>
<tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
```

Is there any way i can use my exact query to search for all words with special characters in it also.
Thanks

Comment: Are all these hits considered equal? Or do you want to boost rows with exact scores? (i.e. would you want `test score` to rank before `test_score`)?

Comment: This is exact match so all results must be there and if boosting can be done then it is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `copyField` to copy the content into multiple fields - one that doesn't change the content (i.e. just a string field or a textfield with keywordtokenizer if you need to lowercase the content) and one field with a StandardTokenizer or similar, allowing you to match "test score" against "test+score" etc.

You can then weight these fields differently by using the edismax query parser, and using `qf` to weigh the fields: `qf=field_exact^5 field` will score an exact match five times higher than matches in the other field.

Use `q.op=AND` to ensure that all terms are present in the resulting document.

Comment: We are already doing that a copy field where actual value is stored and updated field with. I have added field definition here. If you see i am looking for a solution where id o not need to create multiple fields for these scenarios and can save some memory and search in multiple fields

Comment: You can't .. outside of using payloads for scoring, but that will require a lot more manual fixing. Scoring is usually defined per field, so as long as you want to score exact matches more than matching each token by itself, the easiest and most flexible way is to have different fields. If you don't want to score them differently, you don't need the exact matches and a field with StandardTokenizer alone will do.